# Surface composition of Mercury?

Tags: mercury, surface

I've been doing research on the surface composition of Mercury, but it doesn't seem that there are many helpful results online from ArXiv. [One article from PNAS](https://www.pnas.org/content/pnas/77/12/6973.full.pdf) describes the composition of Mercury as a whole, but does not mention its surface features. Are there any resources that detail the surface composition of Mercury, noting most (if not every) compound/element?

Comment: Have you tried wikipedia and references therein?

Comment: @AtmosphericPrisonEscape Yes, I couldn't find anything helpful there. Perhaps you could give me a hint?

Comment: If you have access, relevant publication: http://dx.doi.org/10.1126/science.1211567

Comment: Here is a pdf from arxiv: https://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/1712/1712.02187.pdf

Comment: @NilayGhosh I've already seen this one.